# Prove or disprove: if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{3n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

Need help with this question:

> Prove or disprove: if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then
>   $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{3n}$ converges

I think it's false but I couldn't find any counter example.

Comment: Try $1+0-\frac 12+\frac 13+0-\frac 14+\cdots$  (inserting a $0$ after every positive term in the alternating harmonic series.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false. Consider, for instance:$$-\frac12-\frac12+1-\frac14-\frac14+\frac12-\frac16-\frac16+\frac13-\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
& & & &\text{3rd} & & & & & & \text{6th} & & & & & & \text{9th} \\
& & & & \downarrow & & & & & & \downarrow & & & & & & \downarrow \\
1 & + &  0 & - & \dfrac 1 2 & + & \dfrac 1 3 & + & 0 & - & \dfrac 1 4 & + & \dfrac 1 5 & + & 0 & - & \dfrac 1 6 & + & 0 & + & \dfrac 1 7 & - & \cdots
\end{array}
$$
This whole series converges to $\log_e 2\approx 0.69$ but the terms with indices that are multiples of $3$ diverges to $-\infty.$

However, in the case of series that converge absolutely, the proposed statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a diverging sequence and intersperse terms that cancel them (f.i. $a_{n},-a_{n},0$).